# What does ESRI provide that Google BigQuery cannot provide, and how these two tools can be used together?

Tags: google-bigquery, geospatial, arcgis, esri

Currently I am looking for big data technology that supports Big data Geo-spatial analysis. I came up to ESRI and found its main support for Geo-spatial data analysis and visualization. However, currently, they don't have extensive support for Big Data Geo-spatial analysis, except for the ArcGIS GeoAnalytics Server which requires licensing. At the same time, I found how powerful is Google BigQuery which recently provide support for Geospatial processing and analysis (pay for what you use, per second).

What I would like to know is: which tool I should pick for Geospatial big data processing, analysis and visualization? and which tool (ESRI vs. BigQuery) is better used for what?

I would like to run complex queries on very large temporal Geo-spatial dataset and finally visualize results on a map.

Please note that I have just started my research on Geospatial big data processing and I would like to chose between the alternative tools out there.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(note that Stack Overflow doesn't always welcome this type of questions... but you can always come to https://reddit.com/r/bigquery for more discussions)

For "Geospatial big data processing, analysis and visualization" my favorite recommendation right now is Carto+BigQuery. Carto is one of the leading GIS analysis companies, and they recently announced moving one of their backends to BigQuery. They even published some handy notebooks showing how to work with Carto and BigQuery:

- https://carto.com/blog/carto-google-bigquery-data/